# plotnine change default colormap

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap, plotnine

Is there a way to change the default colormap in plotnine to a custom colormap? I like to avoid adding something like `+ scale_color_manual(custom_palette)`  to all my ggplot figures.

I know how to change the theme for the plotnine figures with `theme_set()`, but is there also something equivalent like `scale_set()`, since scale define the colors in plotnine.

The same applies for changing the datetick format for the x axis when your data has a time index. Is there a global way to set it instead of using `scale_x_datetime(breaks=date_breaks('5 years'), labels=date_format('%Y'))`

In other words, I am looking for something that is equivalent to

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
```

in Matplotlib.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this functionality is provided by `plotnine`. But you can create a subclass of [`ggplot`](https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine/blob/main/plotnine/ggplot.py) to add a color scale by default, then use the subclass to create plots.

```py
from plotnine import *
from plotnine.data import mtcars

class ggplot_color(ggplot):
    def __init__(self, data = None, mapping = None, environment = None):
        super().__init__(data, mapping, environment)
        self.scales.append(scale_color_manual(values=['blue', 'red', 'green']))

g = (ggplot_color(mtcars, aes('wt', 'mpg', color='factor(gear)'))
    + geom_point())
```

[image: sample plot with colors]

Comment: Thank you. This answer is very helpful because it helps to understand how plotnine works more generally. However, since you define scale_color_manual in the new class, I am not sure if it is general enough when using the ggplot_color function also for plots that need continuous color mapping.

Comment: scale_color_manual is just an example here. Should also work with any other color scale.

Comment: @rosab.  Does this need to be added to every script that uses plotnine, or can it be loaded automatically somehow?  Eg added to an initialising script within the plotnine directory or something?

Comment: There are different options, but it is difficult to say what is best in your case without knowing more about how often and where you want to use this functionality. The easiest way is probably to just extend the class (as suggested). This needs to be done once per application. Then you can reuse the class and create an instance wherever you need it (within the application).